# Mongodb $project remove element from array based on a value name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I remove an element from an array with `$project` based on a **"value name"**?
I have the following documents:

```
db.person.insert([
    { "_id": "xvcvdfdff...", "name": [ "mary", "jose", "_id", "jhon" ] } 
    // The _id value can be located anywhere
])
```

And I wish to get the following result:

```
[
    { "_id": "xvcvdfdff...", "name": [ "mary", "jose", "jhon" ] }
]
```

Comment: The insert syntax is not valid.

Comment: @D.SM Thanks for the observation, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following script will intact all values in name array (as well as other document) except the "_id".

```
{
    $project : {
        name : { $filter : { input : "$name", as : "n", cond : { $ne : ["$$n" , "_id"] } } }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem.